# Numpy - row-wise outer product of two matrices

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have two numpy arrays: *A* of shape (b, i) and *B* of shape (b, o). I would like to compute an array *R* of shape (b, i, o) where every line *l* of *R* contains the outer product of the row *l* of *A* and the row *l* of *B*. So far what i have is:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((10, 2))
B = np.ones((10, 6))
R = np.asarray([np.outer(a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B)])
assert R.shape == (10, 2, 6)
```

I think this method is too slow, because of the zip and the final transformation into a numpy array.

Is there a more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is possible with [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), which can do multiplication of "matrix stacks". In this case we want to multiply a stack of column vectors with a stack of row vectors. First bring matrix A to shape (b, i, 1) and B to shape (b, 1, o). Then use matmul to perform b times the outer product:

```
import numpy as np

i, b, o = 3, 4, 5

A = np.ones((b, i))
B = np.ones((b, o))

print(np.matmul(A[:, :, np.newaxis], B[:, np.newaxis, :]).shape)  # (4, 3, 5)
```

An alternative could be to use [`numpy.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which can directly represent your index notation:

```
np.einsum('bi,bo->bio', A, B)
```

Comment: Thank you that is perfect. Accepting your answer as soon as I can

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for sparse matrices?

Comment: @ThomasAhle I've never tried it myself but [opt_einsum](https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the sparse backend sounds promising.

Answer (score 7):

Why not simply

```
A[:, :, None] * B[:, None, :]
```

Depending on your convention and your dtype, you might need to throw in another `np.conj` somewhere. Note that `np.newaxis` is simply `None`